# How can I import imported data from a .json file in a service and then pass that data dynamically into an angular material table?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

How can I import imported data from a .json file in a service and then pass that data dynamically into an angular material table?

I tried replacing ELEMENT_DATA with my property but it doesn't work